# How to return value from Python as JSON?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, json

I sending ajax request from a jQuery file like below, which expects response in JSON.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/Control/getImageDetails?file_id='+currentId,
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data){
        alert(data);
    }
 });
});
```

On Python I sent response to the Ajax request as such:

```
 record = meta.Session.query(model.BannerImg).get(fid)
 return_info = [record.file_id, record.filename, record.links_to]
 return result_info
```

This returns paramaters in plain text making it impossinle to read as different values. i believe sending off response from python as JSON solve this issue. I've nerver used JSON before. How can I return response as JSON?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`return json.dumps(return_info)`

main problem is

```
return_info = [record.file_id, record.filename, record.links_to]
```

because JSON format is generally like

Example:

```
json.dumps({'file_id': record.file_id, 'filename': record.filename , 'links_to' : record.links_to})
```

and the message you are going to receive is `[object Object]` if you use `alert(data)`

So use `alert(data.file_id);` if you use the example

Answer (score 3):

Encode it using the functions in the [`json`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) module.

Comment: e.g.: `return json.dumps(return_info)`

Comment: And it never hurts to have success:True/False in the returned JSON