# Python return object

Tags: python

How would I make Python return something like this:

```
{ "status": error,
  "location": loc,
  "codes": {
      "code1": 5,
      "code2": 6,
  },
}
```

I think this looks like a JSON object?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332465/how-to-return-value-from-python-as-json  this may help you.

Comment: Could you provide a larger sample of code to see where you are trying to return from?  What you have shown here is a Python dictionary, not a JSON object.

Comment: When you ask 'how do I get Python to return <x>', you should indicate what context you mean. Is this a web application? In the REPL? On the command line? From a Python function? You need to add details about where you're working from. See http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to return a dict? https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: Thank you. I think it's more of a dict. The return's from a python function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Literally, the answer to "how do I return this dict" is to *return this dict*:

```
def some_function():
    return {
        "status": error,
        "location": loc,
        "codes": {
            "code1": 5,
            "code2": 6,
        },
    }
```

Comment: Oh this is perfect! I didn't know we can just do `return { XXXXXX }` sorry. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

If that is indeed a JSON object, you would want to use the JSON encoder/decoder that is part of the Python Standard Library. See [the official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html) for more information on it. It has a well-written basic usage section, and good examples.

That library, once imported, should allow you to have functions return JSON objects by using functions like `json.encode` and `json.default`.

Answer (score 0):

What you have in your question looks like a Python dictionary. Since you want to know how one can return something like that, your question has two parts:

- the first part deals with [function usages](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm)
- the second part deals with building up the [dictionary itself](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex39.html)

Luckily, these simple problems are well-documented and one can find the answer with smaller effort than by asking a question.